# Powershell regex match first string ending in pipe character

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm new to powershell, and there seem to be a few differences in the way regex are handled. Currently iterating through a large number of txt files and want the start of each one of them (which is a URL) up to the | character.

The start of every file is a url ending in a slash. This was my umpteenth attempt with no luck:

```
$FirstUrl = '.*/\|$'
```

Pushed through a For-Each loop from which every other piece of information i'm trying to grab is coming out as expected:

```
Foreach-Object {
    $FileContent = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $Pos = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern $FirstURL
```

Any tips on how to phrase the regex right in the $FirstURL. I'm generally 'ok' at regex and have googled my face off trying to find the proper documentation for powershell.

Comment: On a side note: if you just want the first line of each file, why not use `Get-Content -TotalCount 1`. It could drastically speed up your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If each file is having the *URL* in the first line and after that there is a Pipe, then you do not need to use a regex in this case. You can directly split that like:

```
$FileContent = Get-Content $_.FullName
$FileContent.Split('|')[0]
```

Split actually splits the result data into an array. Then the first array element will be in the '0th' index and you can take it out.

Hope it helps.